# Unable to explore SP2013 (O365) apis

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin, core-api

Having just upgraded to SP2013 on O365 (Enterprise) I am keen to take advantage of the various REST endpoints to perform various CRUD operations.

However, I seem unable to drill down into the various api properties and values through any browser.

E.g. I am expecting that by entering something like 'https://my-account.sharepoint.com/_api/web' in the browser I should be returned with information about the site.

However, in IE9 I am returned with an 'Internet Explorer cannot display this feed' message (Feed reading view is enabled, BTW).

In FF and Chrome, I am getting a error code : -2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
.

I am an O365 Admin and have site collection admin privileges so am currently at a loss as to why I am unable to access this data.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IE error could be due to your browser having the feed reading on. Try going into IE's settings, under content Advanced and unclick Turn on feed reading view. This helped me with IE's problem. As for FF and Chrome I am not sure, sorry.